# What is the minimum php version for magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, catalogsearch, php-5.4, php-5.5

i finished my website with magento in PHP 5.5 and the website work correctly 
[image: the search work correctly in localhost]

but when i moved the website online to my server that run in php 5.3 some errors appeared in search 
 [image: the error appeared in the inline copy]

and i did all that steps to fix the errors 
1-flush the cache and log out and in again? 
2-Re-index
3-CatalogSearch enabled in config
4-upload all the files

is the error can be from php version or database !!

Comment: http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Comment: @ADM this is an answer, please post it.

Comment: check your magento index.php `versioncompare()`function to find the reqd version for that magento.

Comment: Did you actually make any searches? It looks to me like there have not been any searches made, hence the non-object, maybe because it's empty?

Answer (score 2):

Minimum PHP version required by Magento 1.9.1.0 is 5.4.

Check requirements on Magento site:

http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [System Requirements for Magento Enterprise Edition and Community Edition](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements).

if you are working with php 5.5, there is no point to downgrade your live environment to 5.3, especially for security reason.

At 1.9.1 index.php

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<')===true) {
 echo  '
  <div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
   <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
     <h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.
     </h3>
   </div>
    <p>Magento supports PHP 5.3.0 or newer.
    <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a> Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
            exit; }
```

**Note:** This question is not about:
why im getting this error on admin page, the question about minimum php version

Comment: is it a good idea to modify the Magento source code? I doubt.

Comment: what? i bet index.php is the most editable file in Magento,

Comment: Nope. There is a reason for having minimum PHP version. For example, If my environment is PHP 5.2, and I change the above code to bypass the check, errors will appear, as there are function changes in between different PHP versions

Comment: lol, Who told you it is a good idea to downgrade? I only show that the requirements specified 5.4, but index.php has 5.3.0...

Answer (score 1):

Although Magento 1.9 should work with PHP 5.3.0 or newer, your error message (which is not from the database) referencing a core file seems to indicate that this is not the case.